# HTML option select without JavaScript

Tags: html, html-select

I've been trying to code a simple option select that would display a div under it after a selection is made. I have completed this action using JavaScript and I am now trying to cater the users that do not use JavaScript.  How am I going to achieve this?

my code goes simply like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
    <li>List Item 4</li>
</li>

<div class="hidden">Details about item 1</div>
<div class="hidden">Details about item 2</div>
<div class="hidden">Details about item 3</div>
<div class="hidden">Details about item 4</div>
```

Comment: can you show a fiddle what have u tried with javascript? so we can get the idea

Comment: To my knowledge it is not possible. All you can do is use a noscript to  let them know that they do not have js

Comment: I don't think you can.  You need some code that actually executes to perform behaviors like this.  Conditional CSS won't do it because it doesn't check the DOM, and there isn't a CSS pseudo class that corresponds to Option Selected.

Comment: you can link to different version of the same window that each display a different div exposed.

Comment: you can do some cool things using only [CSS](http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-pure-css-techniques-for-creating-javascript-like-interactions) but it will be probably impossible to persist past states like hover

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_Enhancement). Show everything, and hide it with script.

If the user doesn't have script the information is still accessible, with script it will be interactive and look nicer.